# How to get the DEBIAN/debian folder from a ".deb" package?

Tags: deb, packing

I would like to know how is possible to get the DEBIAN/debian folder from a ".deb" package.

I found that decompressing a ".deb" package using decompressing tools such as p7zip or dpkg decompress only the software that is going to be installed, and I was thinking that A software can be all free/open source etc, but how can you be sure that there are no Mallory post/pre installation scripts in the ".deb" package?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming and more suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
dpkg -e path/to/deb
```

For more info, see [man dpkg-deb](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg-deb&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&locale=).

Comment: Thanks! the -e option wasn't appearing when using 'dpkg --help'